# Emacs custom language auto-indentation

Tags: unix, emacs, programming-languages, elisp, indentation

I'm writing a major mode for editing my custom language sources with Emacs (although I don't know Lisp). Syntax highlighting is very easy to implement, but now I'm trying to setup the auto-indentation and I can't.

I have test [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158816/972197) and it is perfect for `'{'`, `'['`, `']'` and `'}'` characters. For example, in my tests, if I change `"[[{]"` regex by `"[[:]"`, it doesn't auto-indent with `':'`. Why? I'm going crazy!

My real purpose is to indent blocks between `if` and `endif` keywords, and between `while` and `endwhile` keywords. For example:

```
if a > 0
    b = 2
    while b = 2
        a = 0
    endwhile
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto-indentation is not as simple as syntax highlighting, by a long stretch.  There is precious little generic support for indentation.  If you're using a recent enough Emacs, you might like to try and use the SMIE package.  Maybe a good way to try it out is to look at how octave-mod.el uses it (e.g. in Emacs-24).  But don't expect it to be easy.